com.facebook.react.internal.turbomodule.core.TurboModuleInteropUtils$ParsingException:
Exception in HostObject::get for prop 'ExtSdkApiRN': com.facebook.react.internal.turbomodule.core.TurboModuleInteropUtils$ParsingException: Unable to parse @ReactMethod annotation from native module method: ExtSdkApiRN.listeners(). Details: Unable to parse JNI signature. Detected unsupported return class: java.lang.Object[] [Component Stack]
when usng react-native-agora-chat--1.3.0-alpha-0 && react-natve --0.76.1
Please help me how to solve
it shows error in the line
const chatClient = ChatClient.getInstance();
TypeError: Cannot read property 'ChatClient' of undefined

you should add some code so someOne can help you.

This is coming from react-native-agora-chat
import {
ChatClient,
ChatOptions,
} from 'react-native-agora-chat';const chatClient = ChatClient.getInstance(); for the above line please help

The error is in the external SDK used in the module. I can't raise a PR because the repo isn't on Github or I'm not sure where they publish the source.
Error Detail:
Unable to parse JNI signature. Detected unsupported return class: java.lang.Object[]
So the return type java.lang.Object[] is unsupported.
Solution:
Return a supported type which is WritableArray
Quick Fix:

Go to \node_modules\react-native-agora-chat\native_src\java\com\easemob\ext_sdk\rn\ExtSdkApiRN.java

Import WritableArray


import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableArray;


Change the return type of listeners() from Object[] to WritableArray

// Line: 154

    @ReactMethod
    public WritableArray listeners(String methodType) throws Exception {
        // Keep: Required for RN built in Event Emitter Calls.
        throw new Exception("Required for RN built in Event Emitter Calls.");
    }



Clear cache and rebuild the app.


There's a support issue for many libraries in the new RN architecture at the moment (RN 0.76 >). You might have to check for patches or downgrade.
